Loading module from “URL/chunk-TWQM45PI.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
I am trying to dockerise an angular application and deploy it to K8's, once I load my page I get these errors for all chunks, these files reside in the same folder as index.html, I am trying with nginx server.

Application works in local environment when building and serving with ng.
I tried various solutions reccomended online but no luck.

Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?  Does the application work in simpler environments, like Docker Compose or plain Node without a container environment?  When it serves the image file you've included, what code produces that image, and what output do you inspect instead?
